# Update class from another class, encapsulation issue

Tags: c#, design-patterns, encapsulation

How must I update a class, which must be updated only from another specific class?

In the following example encapsulation is broken, because `Sensor` can be updated from any other class, not only from `Device`. Am I right?

```
class Device
{
    public IEnumerable<Sensor> Sensors { get; private set; }

    void SomeInternalCall(int sensorId, int signal)
    {
        Sensors.First(s => s.Id == sensorId).Update(signal);
    }

}

class Sensor
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public event Action<int> OnSignal;

    public void Update(int signal)
    {
        if (OnSignal != null) OnSignal(signal);
    }
}

class SensorUser
{
    public SensorUser(Sensor s)
    {
        s.OnSignal += SignalHandler;
    }

    void SignalHandler(int signal)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Should Sensor be available to other classes outside of Device?  i.e. Must it be a publicly accessable class?!

Comment: Yes, it must be used by `SensorUser` class which is outside the `Device`

Comment: Could you just expand on "because Sensor can be updated from any other class, not only from Device." - the only property you have is private set, so nothing else *can* update it?

Comment: By updating I mean calling Sensor's method `Update(int signal)`. It is public, so any other class can call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface that provides read-only access and give it to `SensorUser`, while having a collection of `Sensor` instances in `Device`.

```
interface ISensor
{
    int Id { get;  }    
    event Action<int> OnSignal;
}

class Sensor : ISensor
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }    
    public event Action<int> OnSignal;

    public void Update(int signal)
    {
        if (OnSignal != null) OnSignal(signal);
    }
}

class SensorUser
{
    public SensorUser(ISensor s)
    {
        s.OnSignal += SignalHandler;
    }    
}
```

Comment: OP code already states "public int Id { get; *private* set; }", so I think your answer just abstracts it away?!  Think the question is a little unclear as to what should and shouldn't be updated.

Comment: OP is asking how to hide the Update method from SensorUser, and interface helps with that.