# Update class X created by class A from class B. Encapsulation issue

Tags: c#, design-patterns, encapsulation

Previous question (easier): [Update class from another class, encapsulation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107764/update-class-from-another-class-encapsulation-issue)

Example:

```
class User
{
    public void BeginWork(Device device)
    {
        Command command = new Command(1);

        device.ExecuteCommand(command);

        Console.WriteLine("Result={0}", command.Result);
    }
}

class Command
{
    public int Code {get; private set;}

    public Command(int code) { Code = code; }

    public int Result { get; set; }
}

class Device
{

    public void ExecuteCommand(Command command)
    {
        /* ... */

        // Analyzing and execution of command leads to a result

        if(command.Code == 1) command.Result = 5;
        else if(command.Code == 2) command.Result = 36;

        /* ... */
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
        User u = new User();
        Device d = new Device();
        u.BeginWork(d);
```

As you see, encapsulation is broken by public set accessor of property `Result` of class `Command`

Do not propose to change method `ExecuteCommand` to return the result. Real situation is much more complicated.

How to keep encapsulation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, what do you wish to encapsulate?

Comment: Property `Result` of `Command` must be set only by `Device`. Now setter is public for everybody

Comment: Why is `User` creating the command and then passing it to `Device`?  Why not have `Device` create the `Command` and return it from the method?

Comment: May be, that it is not obvious from this example, but `Command` must contain some properties, and `User` must assign them. For example, `Timeout` or `Name` property. I will edit an example

Comment: @astef Why not just have `ExecuteCommand` accept an `int` as a parameter and return another `int`?  Why do you need to create a class to represent both the parameter list and the return value?

Comment: @Servy Because in real project `Command` is far more complicated, the same as it's result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to separate the concepts of a Request and Result.  So you have a CommandRequest, and a CommandResult class.  Then the Device class can construct the CommandResult class and there need be no public setters on it (immutable).

Answer (score 0):

Define Command and Device in an assembly and User in another assembly. Then make setter of Result internal.

```
public int Result { get; internal set; }
```